# What is the difference between 「届け」and 「届ける」？

Tags: translation, keigo, godan-verbs

Found a phrase on article which says,

> 写真{しゃしん}をお届{とど}け!

i don't think it's meireikei, so why the verb doesn't end with ru?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 写真をお届け!

I think it's short for

> 写真をお届けします！
>   or 写真をお届けいたします！

"We will deliver a photo/photos to you!"

お届けする is the humble form (謙譲語) of 届ける.

Examples:

> ～をご報告 / ご案内 / ご連絡 / ご紹介(いた)します！--> ～をご報告！/ご案内！/ご連絡！/ご紹介！
>   キャンペーン情報をお知らせ(いた)します！--> キャンペーン情報をお知らせ！

[image]

Comment: 確かに、こっちでしたね。………

Answer (score -2):

It's short for お届けなさい. (It's not included in Standard Japanese, i.e. it's dialectal.)